# Get controller name from $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to get the controller name from the current $scope in AngularJS?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to know it, you could always let your controller put its name on `$scope.controllerName`.

Comment: You're right, but it's not so usable because I and everyone who collaborate with me should have to remember to put controller's name in a $scope variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible. What if `$scope` belongs to directive? There is no property that can retrieve information about the controller the scope belongs to.

Comment: Your question was the first problem I thought about. So there's no way to do that without hacking angularJs's core right?

Comment: @tommasocapelli There is no way. You need to assign the name as a property manually.

Comment: Thank you so much, that would have been my solution if I haven't found any other ways to get controller's name in $scope.

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure this is a good solution, but I was able to inject `$scope.controllerName` using this technique:

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', [
        '$delegate',
        function ($delegate) {
            return function(constructor, locals) {
                if (typeof constructor == "string") {
                    locals.$scope.controllerName =  constructor;
                }

                return $delegate.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
            }
        }]);
}]);
```

Then

```
app.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {
    $log.log("[" + $scope.controllerName +"] got here");
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The code works fine in angular 1.2.x but is broken in 1.3. demo: http://jsbin.com/muqipe/3/edit?html,console,output  After tracing source code, I found that two more arguments is missing for 1.3, so it should be "function(constructor, locals, later, indent)" and "$delegate(constructor, locals, later, indent)", for your reference.

Comment: Darkthread you are a saviour, and keving same for offering the initial answer :)

Answer (score 12):

So, based on the answer from Kevin Hakanson and the comment from Darkthread, this code works with at least 1.3.15:dev

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        return function (constructor, locals, later, indent) {
            if (typeof constructor === 'string' && !locals.$scope.controllerName) {
                locals.$scope.controllerName = constructor;
            }
            return $delegate(constructor, locals, later, indent);
        };
    }])
}]);
```

Comment: this doesnt work if you minify your app, how do you ensure the names of the arguments even in a minified file?

Comment: In my case I use gulp to deploy my application. So I was able to adress this problem using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate

Comment: A slightly better approach for params is using the actual arguments that have been sent to the controller:
return $delegate.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));

Answer (score 8):

This also works for me. I needed a function to determine if the controller name matched a given route, when using 'ngRoute' to select a controller, so I did this:

```
app.controller('navigation', function($scope, $route) {
  $scope.tab = function(route) {
    return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
  }
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="navigation" class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href='#/'>home</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('dashboard')}"><a href='#/dashboard'>dashboard</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where I have already added routes to my config, e.g. something like

```
angular.module('app', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(
    function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.otherwise('/');
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller : 'home'
        }).when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl : 'dashboard.html',
            controller : 'dashboard'
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 5):

In controller factory function, just try ***$attrs*** service

```
app.controller("MyController", ["$attrs", function($attrs){

      var currentControllerName = $attrs["ngController"];

}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

just `this.constructor.name` anywhere that the scope of that class is available once instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

The question is getting a little old but it might still be helpful for some of you... I found a way to get controller name **but** it only works with a `Controller as` syntax. I can now do my logging more easily without having to manually re-write my controller name every single time. Here is an example:

```
// a simple route with controller as syntax
$routeProvider.when(
    '/contact', 
    { 
        templateUrl: 'home/contact', 
        controller: 'ContactController as vm' 
    }
);

// controller
app.controller("ContactController", ["$log", function ContactController($log) {
    var vm = this;
    $log.log(vm.constructor.name); 
}]);
```

If you want to do it from the DOM (from javascript legacy code), you could also do it this way:

```
// scope element via the DOM
var scope = angular.element($(element)).scope();    
console.log(scope.this.vm.constructor.name);

// controller element via the DOM
var controller = angular.element($(element)).controller();    
console.log(controller.constructor.name);
```

**Edit**
Also tried the suggestion of [Dave Syer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27600777) it actually works on `$scope` as for example:

```
app.controller("ContactController", ['$route', function ContactController($route) {
  console.log($route.current.controller);
}]);
```

Comment: This is wonderful! I work on a large project and it is much easier to find exactly which controller I need to look at for a given element on the page by clicking on it and run `angular.element($0).controller().constructor.name` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get scope of directive as well as scope of controller using jQuery.

```
 window.top.$('[ng-controller="mainCtrl"]').scope(); // get scope of controller

 window.top.$('[epubby-page-view]').scope(); // get scope of directive
```

We can execute a method or update any variable from anywhere using this scope fetching methods.

For example:
consider we want to execute a method from mainCtrl controller,
we just need to give a direct call to method as follows:

```
var myData = window.top.$('[ng-controller="mainCtrl"]').scope().getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging from the console, this I found useful:

1. Select the element in the UI whose controller you are searching for in Chrome dev tools
2. Input in the console: `angular.element($0).controller().__proto__`

It will get you the prototype of the controller, inside its constructor, there is `FunctionLocation`that corresponds to a file. If you make your controllers one per file like you should, you found your controller there. It's even better if you name your files as a controller, I don't see why you would not.

I know it's not exactly what you asked for but I find it helpful and extremely easy to use right from the dev tools.