# Get module and controller|service|directive names at runtime

Tags: angularjs, logging

Over at [angular-logger](https://github.com/pdorgambide/angular-logger), we are trying to enhance `$log`, but we would like to work in the name of the angular's module and component without changes. To do so we need to get the AngularJS *context* at runtime, that is, the *module name* and *controller, service* or *directive* names.

```js
app.module("SampleModule").
   controller("ControllerOne", function ($log) {
      $log.debug("I am ready!")
   }).
   controller("ControllerTwo", function ($log) {
      $log.debug("I am ready!")
   });
```

Default `$log` output:

```
> I am ready!
> I am ready!
```

If we can obtain the module and controller name at runtime, then using the enhanced `$log` we can get richer output:

```
> SampleModule.ControllerOne: I am ready!
> SampleModule.ControllerTwo: I am ready!
```

The best option will be to get it without changes to the controller's code. Perhaps there is way to get some meta info about the entities that received the $log dependency injection?

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can create a directive ng-controller, which would execute for every controller and parse the content provided to ng-controller as string and set it on some variable in score.. and then use that variable to print controller name

Comment: angular does execute all the directive if found multiple directives with same name

Answer (score 6):

There was a [similar question that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382734/angularjs-get-controller-name-from-scope) on SO, but the solution works only when using controller as syntax.

```
// a simple route with controller as syntax
$routeProvider.when(
    '/myRoute', 
    { 
        templateUrl: '/myRoute', 
        controller: 'ControllerOne as vm' 
    }
);

// controller
app.controller("ControllerOne", ['$log', function ControllerOne($log) {
    var vm = this;
    $log.log(vm.constructor.name); 
}]);
```

Comment: @Plantface, I saw your edit. Why do you think "The angular array annotation is superfluous for educational purposes".

Comment: The array annotation is used to work around an issue that only happens during minification. In this case it has no added value and only helps to obscure relevant info. [su·per·flu·ous, adj.: _exceeding what is sufficient or required_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/superfluous)

Comment: It is a shame that only works for controller and left out log enhaced capabilities for services and directives. I get in mind to solve wrapping with an context execution, time ago I read about a framework that make this for test or thread execution but i don't remember its name.

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation, but couldn't find any way around it. Please share if you manage to solve this problem in future.

Comment: The answer is partially correct, but is also misleading since there is no need for "controller as" - you only need to have the controller function (in this case, `ControllerOne` - the function name, not the controller) to be named - i.e. not anonymous. In other words, this would not work: `.controller("MainCtrl", function(){..})` even with "controller as". So,

Comment: @AbhishekJain, I removed your rant from the post, next time I will flag it for moderator intervention. I'm not debating the merit of array annotation, which obviously exist for a reason. But as a teacher who, in front of a class, will reduce an example to its bare essential to illustrate a problem, code examples on SO should focus on the problem/solution as well. However, I'm not going to spend more energy on something as minor as array notation. All the best and thank you for trying to help OP solve his problem.