# I want to know if there is any way through which I can know which controller is associated to my partial by typing something in my html?

Tags: angularjs, controller, partial

I want to know if there is any way through which I can know which controller is associated to my partial by typing something in my html?

Many times it happens I have to search a lot in order to find the exact controller associated with my template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get controller name from $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382734/get-controller-name-from-scope)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using routing you can do something like this:

```
{{ $route.current.controller }}
```