# Need a static unique identifier from an angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've got a series of controllers that make a common call to a function in a parent controller. The behavior of that function will depend on which controller calls it. Currently, I handle this by passing a key as an argument:

In controllerOne:

```
var result = $scope.getQuery('controllerOne');
```

In controllerTwo:

```
var result = $scope.getQuery('controllerTwo');
```

This works, but I can't help but feel like there's got to be some way to autogenerate that key so that it remains consistent every time the parent function is called. Something along these lines:

```
var result = $scope.getQuery(this.$id);
```

So that others can just drop the call into different places without worrying about what the key is. this.$id doesn't work, as it changes on each call, but something like that. Is there a way to get the controller's name, maybe? Anything that is unique and static would suffice.

Comment: what about [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24091306/8495123), you would get it in a form `$scope.getQuery($scope.controllerName);`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey that ends up being 'undefined', but that's the type of thing I'm looking for...I figure every controller has a name, I'm just not sure how to access it, assuming it's possible.